# Suggestions for Building/Designing Desktop Custom "Text Editor" like Application for OSX

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, desktop-application, text-editor

I'm trying to build a relatively simple text editor type application for OSX. I'm completely new to developing apps and was looking for some suggestions for the best approach to build something to display and edit text in a non-standard form. Text will be taken from some input file and then edited. I need the window to be structured something like this:

```
Header1   String1
Header2   String2
Header3   String3
etc.
```

There could be a 100s of headers and corresponding strings, with each string potentially being 1000s of characters (headers are short). Every character in the string must line up with the corresponding characters on the string below. For example, the 1st character of every string would be in the same "column" and so on. Since the strings will likely not fit in the window entirely, I'd need to scroll to see every character.

I need to be able to click on individual characters and perform different actions on them (ie. delete character, color character). I also want to be able to select and highlight regions and perform actions on those regions. For example, I may want to select and highlight a region of text and delete it (ie. select a column of characters and delete them or maybe select a block of characters and highlight them).

I've done a couple Xcode tutorials for building desktop applications and looked through the documentation but haven't come across an object that seems to fit the bill. Initially, I thought about using something like NSTableView but I think that'll have too much overhead (especially as input files get massive). Any suggestions on possible objects or ways of implementing this I could use to do this?

I'd prefer to not have to literally draw the characters on a coordinate system and build the application that way but am unsure if I have a better option. From what I understand, I could do this using an NSCustomView somehow and the NSLayoutManager.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you investigated NSTextView?